# Inertia tensor in canonical and rotated basis

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

So say we can describe some angular velocity $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ in canonical basis, $\{\mathbf{e}_i\}$, and a rotated basis, $\{\mathbf{\tilde{e}}_i\}$, like

$$\boldsymbol{\omega}=\omega_1\mathbf{e}_1+\omega_2\mathbf{e}_2+\omega_3\mathbf{e}_3=\tilde{\omega}_1\mathbf{\tilde{e}}_1+\tilde{\omega}_2\mathbf{\tilde{e}}_2+\tilde{\omega}_3\mathbf{\tilde{e}}_3,$$

and its coordinates in each basis and their basis are related by the rotational matrix $\mathbf{R}$ in the following way:
$$\begin{aligned}
\begin{pmatrix}
\tilde{\omega}_1\\
\tilde{\omega}_1\\
\tilde{\omega}_1
\end{pmatrix}=\mathbf{R}
\begin{pmatrix}
\omega_1\\
\omega_2\\
\omega_3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}\ \text{and}\ 
\begin{aligned}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{\tilde{e}}_1\\
\mathbf{\tilde{e}}_2\\
\mathbf{\tilde{e}}_3
\end{pmatrix}=\mathbf{(R^{-1})}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{e}_1\\
\mathbf{e}_2\\
\mathbf{e}_3
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{aligned}$$

Then, what I want to ask is whether when calculating the angular momentum in canonical basis,
$$\mathbf{L_e}=\mathcal{I_e}\boldsymbol{\omega_{e}}$$
and in rotated basis
$$\mathbf{L_{\tilde{e}}}=\mathcal{I_{\tilde{e}}}\boldsymbol{\omega_{\tilde{e}}},$$

would $\mathcal{I_e}=\mathcal{I_{\tilde{e}}}$?

Because I thought that maybe if
$$(\mathcal{I_{ij}})_e=\iiint_V \rho(r^2\delta_{ij}-x_ix_j) dV$$

then
$$(\mathcal{I_{ij}})_{\tilde{e}}=\iiint_\tilde{V} \rho(r^2\delta_{ij}-\tilde{x}_i\tilde{x}_j) d\tilde{V}.$$

Note that $\mathbf{\tilde{x}}=\mathbf{Rx}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't be the same.

$$    (I_{\tilde e})_{ij} = \int_V \rho (\tilde r^2 \delta_{ij}-\tilde x_i \tilde x _j)$$
of course $r^2 = \tilde{\mathbf{r}} \cdot  \tilde{\mathbf{r} } = (\mathbf{R}\mathbf{r})^{\mathrm{tr}}\cdot \mathbf{R} \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{R}\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{r}$. This is true for any scalar, also the square of the angular momentum.
Let us go back to the formula
$$    (I_{\tilde e})_{ij} = \int_V \rho (\tilde r^2 \delta_{ij}-R_{ia}x_a\,R_{jb} x_b)$$
which differs from $ (I_{e})_{ij}$.